# Deploying the Restlet web project from Intelij to apache tomcat?

Tags: xml, tomcat, restlet, intellij-13

I have a JAVA-EE project which uses "restlet-2.2" framework in my Intellij 13.1.4.

I want to deploy this project to ***apache tomcat*** server but I am having some problems.

Project structure

1.I have some JAVA classes which are basically different web services. All these classes extend **ServerResource** class. These classes have @Get methods inside them which will respond to the client request.

2.Then I have a class **MyServer** which extends **Application** class and in MyServer I have a Router class object which basically routes the requests to appropriate web-services depending on the URI.

3.web.xml -  Intellij by defaults creates a web.xml with version="3.1" and adds **nothing** into it. So I modified that web.xml(Adding the web.xml below)

I have done the artifacts configurations and in my "war exploded" I have following structure

```
WEB-INF 
 --classes
    -----| All compiled class files
 --lib
    -----| restlet jar files and json jar files (org.json.jar org.restlet.jar org.restlet.ext.json.jar org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar)
 --web.xml
```

When I put this exploded war in my apache tomcat webapps folder and restart tomcat then I am able to access the html/css/js files. But my AJAX calls always give ERROR 404. I have tried all the solutions from stackoverflow and other websites but nothing helped.

***web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <!-- Application class name -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>
            MyServer
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Restlet adapter -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Catch all requests -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServerServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/Projects/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

***MyServer class***

```
    Router classpublic class MyServer extends Application{

        public static void main(String []args)
        {
            Component component = new Component();
            component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8080);
            Application application = new MyServer();
            // Attach the application to the component and start it
            component.getDefaultHost().attach(application);
            try {
                component.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Method for attaching the URIs for web services
        public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot()
        {
            Router router = new Router(getContext());

            //System.out.println("In router");

            //Attaching URIsl
            router.attach("/Projects/{projectID}/Enclosures/{enclID}/getStructure", StructureCalculations.class);
    }
}
```

And my AJAX call URI looks like this

```
http://localhost:8080/Projects/p1/Enclosures/e1/getStructure?param1=x&param2=y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer here:
https://vatsalad.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/how-to-setup-a-servlet-based-restlet-webservice/

However, I think why you don't deploy your restlet project like as a window service instead of web application?
Because, anyway web application will must run in a web service platform that is tomcat. Really, When you run restlet application then it also like as tomcat. It will listen request from a specific port that you set in your code.